# How to remove minuses in a tornado/bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a chart(horizontalBar modified to a tornado chart) in chart.js that goes from -100 to 100. But I don't want the chart to visually display the minuses in front of the numbers on the left side. Any suggestions on how to remove them?

I've also unsuccessfully tried to draw lines from top to bottom that indicates the values(unclear, moderate, clear etc) written below on the chart. Any help with that would also be much appreciated.

```
<canvas id="bar-chart-horizontal" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
 <div class="row justify-content-between">
 <a href="#">Very clear</a> | <a href="#">Clear</a> | <a href="#">Moderate</a> | <a href="#">Unclear</a> | <a href="#">Moderate</a> | <a href="#">Clear</a> | <a href="#">Very clear</a>
 </div>
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-horizontal"), {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ["", "", "", ""],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Strenght",
                backgroundColor: ["#004070", "#ff2384", "#004070", "#ff2384"],
                data: [61, 35, -29, 13]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: { display: false },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Score'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    suggestedMin: -100,
                    suggestedMax: 100
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

[Code on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkea8z2q/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options.scales.xAxes.ticks` has a `callback` that can be used to manipulate the value as it should be displayed.

Docs:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration

```
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: value => value.toString().replace('-', '')
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lkea8z2q/11/

Comment: thanks for feedback. But I need to display numbers, only that the minuses are removed on the left side.

Comment: Sorry @JohanHerstad, I forgot to save the fiddle :) Example is working as expected now, also I added the code needed here.